# Create MySQL database on server

Tags: database, connection, database-connection, mysql

I'm following a tutorial for constructing a PHP and MySQL ecommerce driven website, and I'm uploading them to my server at the moment, but in need of some assistance determining how to proceed.

In the `README` of the tutorial, are the following instructions:

```
INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS

1.) Unzip plaincart.zip to the root folder under your 
    HTTP directory ( or under your preferred directory) 


2.) Create a database and database user on your web
    server for Plaincart

3.) Use the sql dump in plaincart.sql to generate the
    tables and example data

4.) Modify the database connection settings in 
    library/config.php.

5.) If you want to accept paypal modify the settings
    in include/paypal/paypal.inc.php . More information
    about this paypal stuff can be found in 
    http://www.phpwebcommerce.com/shop-checkout-process/
```

OK, so I obviously am capable enough to complete #1! :)

So, on to number 2, how to I create a database on my server?

I understad number 3, referring to the fact that I use the SQL dump file to construct some sample data once the database has been created.

I can't tell about #4 and #5 yet, but we'll see when we get there.

So, I guess I just need to know how to construct a MySQL database on my web server.

Comment: do you also have a file for the schema of the database that you are creating? It sounds like quite the task to import data into a schema that you don't have any information about.

Comment: What do you mean by schema?  I have a SQL dump.. If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: install [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php) on the remote server, and do it from that web interface.

Comment: actually I think I would disagree with you on this one. I started out using the command line interface for mysql and i found phpmyadmin to be not very intuitive at first.

Comment: what is the default username and password for my phpmyadmin.  Also, I just drop the folder right onto my server, correct?

Comment: 1. Yes, you just drop it in somewhere.  2. phpMA just passes that into mySQL, so it's whatever your DB uname/pw is.  3. There are advantages to both; I started on phpMA instead of console, so found it easier.  If you don't have an SSH tunnel in though, the mySQL part can be tricker though (you have to log in from a non-localhost address, and thus have to give access to one).  4. Your SQL dump probably has a line or two near the top that say CREATE [SCHEMA, TABLE, etc.].  The 'import' function of phpMA should let you upload and use that file.